# Get maximum seq no from a SQL table

Tags: c#, sql

I am new to c# and I am confused at this point that,

I have a table (MASTER) in SQL server database with fields like SEQ_NO AND EMP_NAME
and there are multiple users inserting records in this table via a C#.NET winform application
at the same time

I am generating insert statement like this

```
(INSERT INTO MASTER (SEQ_NO,EMP_NAME)
  VALUES( (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(SEQ_NO) ,0)+1), 'ABC')   for every users.
```

Now many-a-times it happens that one or more user end up getting same SEQ_NO,
of course because I have taken

```
(SELECT ISNULL(MAX(SEQ_NO) ,0)+1), 'ABC').
```

So is there any other way to maintain these SEQ_NO series.
Can anyone one help me out here, It would be great full.

Comment: Why not use an `IDENTITY` column?

Comment: Assuming you are using MSSQL and not ORACLE then as said by other users you can achieve this by setting the SEQ_NO column to be an identity.

Answer (score 1):

Make SEQ_NO as an [**IDENITY**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column and sit back and relax . Read the examples in the link.

Comment: This has one caveat - you can only have one `IDENTITY` column per table. Of course, you're probably doing something wrong if you need two, but I'm still posting this for completeness :) And of course, if you don't want the sequence number globally unique inside the table then identity doesn't help you.

Comment: Actually there is a lot of sense in multiple sequence per table, just not global. Items like "Line Number" or "Item Number" are often sequences within a larger context (like invoice line, order item).

Comment: Thanks my friend , but suppose if every user is inserting bulk records

Comment: Thanks my friend , but suppose if all user are inserting bulk records ,say about 20-25 records at the same time, the IDENTITY field will raise error because it is a primary key column.

Comment: @user3541569 No it doesn't, `IDENTITY` guarantees unique values to be generated.

Comment: @user3541569 every record being inserted will generate unique value in column declared as IDENITY .. No tension

Answer (score 1):

Use IDENTITY column for auto increment value. Follow [IDENTITY (Property) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define `SEQ_NO` as an `IDENTITY` column? It will automatically insert next value when you insert into `EMP_NAME`. I think that would be the best option (always better than using exclusive lock for insert).